# Como hago un vector de enteros sin conocer su longitud Java

Tags: java, array

Necesito almacenar los divisores primos de un numero 'x' en un array
Como no se cuantos divisores primos tiene ese numero, no puedo determinar el tamaño del array.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class vectorDivisoresPrimos { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        int n,m=0; 
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in); 
        n = scan.nextInt(); 
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++) 
        { 
            m=EsPrimo(i); 
            if(n%i==0&&m<2) 
            { 
                //Aquí es donde necesito guardar a 'i' en el array o la lista// 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    public static int EsPrimo(int x) 
    { 
        int c=0; 
        for(int j=1;j<x;j++) 
        { 
            if(x%j==0)  c++; 
        } 
        return c; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido José, recuerda que es recomendable agregar lo que has realizado. Revisar [ask].

Comment: Hola José, Puede usar `List` para tamaños de datos desconocidos (**probablemente `ArrayList` sea ​​la mejor solución para usted**).

Comment: Concuerdo con @J.Rodríguez. `ArrayList` te va a quitar muchos problemas por que de otra manera tendrias que redimensionar el array una y otra vez.

Comment: Si te obligan a utilizar un array normal, recuerda que el máximo número de divisores es la mitad del número a dividir, aunque suelen ser bastantes menos...

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;


public class vectorDivisoresPrimos {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  int n,m=0;
  Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
     n = scan.nextInt();
     for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
     {
      m=EsPrimo(i);
      if(n%i==0&&m<2)
      {
       //Aquí es donde necesito guardar a 'i' en  el array o la lista//
      }
     }
 }
 public static int EsPrimo(int x)
 {
  int c=0;
  for(int j=1;j<x;j++)
  {
   if(x%j==0) 
    c++;
  }
  return c;

 }

}

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> suVector = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: Gracias @J.Rodríguez :)

Comment: también podría servirte esto:
https://blog.openalfa.com/como-usar-arrays-de-tamano-variable-en-java

Comment: Mejor `List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();`. Además haria una correccion de optimización: Cambia tu if por `if(n%i==0&&EsPrimo(i)<2)`